# Экзамены Кембриджские или кембриджские?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, названия

Это относится к системе международных экзаменов, которые проводятся по всему миру в авторизованных центрах. Не в Кембридже! Как в этом случае правильно писать "Авторизованный кембриджский экзаменационный центр RU027"? Он находится в России. Какие слова с заглавной?

Answer (score 1):

**Кембриджские экзамены** — это официальное название системы тестов, оно является **именем собственным** и обычно пишется с прописной буквы.

Но в неофициальном текстах встречается написание со строчной буквы, в этом случае название считается **нарицательным**, например:

Наши слушатели, изучая английский язык в течение учебного года по аутентичным учебникам Cambridge University Press, сдав пробные экзамены в феврале, сдают **кембриджские экзамены** в конце учебного года – в мае.

**Справочная информация**

**Кембриджские экзамены или Cambridge ESOL** - это система тестов, разработанных и проводимых подразделением Кембриджского университета, University of Cambridge Local Examinations Syndicate или UCLES. Это подразделение не ведет учебную работу и не является коммерческой организацией. UCLES (и ее торговая марка Cambridge Assessment) создана для проведения международного сертифицирования владения английским у тех, чьим родным языком не является английский.

Язык: **британский вариант** английского языка. Преимущество этих экзаменов в том, что их сертификаты имеют признание во всем мире.

[Кембриджские экзамены: Cambridge ESOL | education-medelle.com](http://www.education-medelle.com/articles/kembridzhskie-ekzameni-cambridge-esol.html)

Answer (score 0):

Эказмены Кембриджские, потому что их проводит специальное подразделение Кембриджского университета или другой экзаменационный центр, этим университетом уполномоченный. Экзаменационный центр Кембриджский (Кембриджский экзаменационный центр), потому что проводит  Кембриджские эказмены, это не название центра.